# Python group data into one hour intervals

Tags: python

I'm working on a large dataset in which the instances are provided with a timestamp. All the data is loaded into a dataframe.A short snippet of the entries:

```
2015-05-12 14:35:49
2015-05-13 09:56:48
2015-05-07 11:01:15
2015-05-13 11:00:04
2015-05-05 13:21:27
```

I wanna group data into one hour intervals and count them. So the result of the task should be something like this:

```
Time Interval     Count
08:00-09:00        2
09:00-10:00        3
10:00-11:00        4
```

Is there an efficient way to perform this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
df.groupby(df['date'].map(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

times = [
'2015-05-01 14:05:49',
'2015-05-12 14:35:49',
'2015-05-13 09:56:48',
'2015-05-07 11:01:15',
'2015-05-13 11:00:04',
'2015-05-23 11:30:04',
'2015-05-05 13:21:27',
]

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(times), columns=['date'])

print(df.groupby(df['date'].map(lambda x: x.hour)).describe())
```

Output:

```
                            date
date
9    count                     1
     unique                    1
     top     2015-05-13 09:56:48
     freq                      1
     first   2015-05-13 09:56:48
     last    2015-05-13 09:56:48
11   count                     3
     unique                    3
     top     2015-05-07 11:01:15
     freq                      1
     first   2015-05-07 11:01:15
     last    2015-05-23 11:30:04
13   count                     1
     unique                    1
     top     2015-05-05 13:21:27
     freq                      1
     first   2015-05-05 13:21:27
     last    2015-05-05 13:21:27
14   count                     2
     unique                    2
     top     2015-05-01 14:05:49
     freq                      1
     first   2015-05-01 14:05:49
     last    2015-05-12 14:35:49
```

Comment: This one worked. But is it also possible to differ the time interval? So let's say to group them in two hour intervals?

Comment: Have a look at pandas.TimeGrouper or/and pandas.Grouper classes

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the timestamp, take just he hour and based on that update entries in a dictionary for your time intervals. See https://eval.in/511344

```
times = [
'2015-05-12 14:35:49',
'2015-05-13 09:56:48',
'2015-05-07 11:01:15',
'2015-05-13 11:00:04',
'2015-05-05 13:21:27',
]

intervals = {}

for t in times:
    hr = t[11:13]
    if hr not in intervals:
       intervals[hr] = 0
    intervals[hr]+=1

print intervals

for k in sorted(intervals.keys()):
    print "%s:00-%s:00  %s" % (k,int(k)+1,intervals[k])
```

Which prints

```
# 09:00-10:00  1
# 11:00-12:00  2
# 13:00-14:00  1
# 14:00-15:00  1
```

Based on @MaxU answer though, seems you are dealing with Python/Panda, which in my answer is not actually considered. The method is the same: you group the set by the hour.